Understanding Windows IOCP and Overlapped I/O: Order of Completion and Message Sequencing
I have two questions regarding Windows IOCP (I/O Completion Ports) and Overlapped I/O:
1. Order of Asynchronous I/O Operations:
In Jeffrey Richter's book Windows Via C/C++, the following statement is made:

"You should be aware of a couple of issues when performing asynchronous I/O. First, the device driver doesn't have to process queued I/O requests in a first-in first-out (FIFO) fashion."

This implies that when calling Overlapped I/O functions, the operations might not be processed in the order they were initiated. Here's an example:
// part of iocp tcp server
WSASend( ... ); // 1
WSASend( ... ); // 2
WSASend( ... ); // 3

Is Windows allowed to process the WSASend calls out of the order in which they were called? However, since TCP inherently guarantees message order, how is message sequencing ensured when using Overlapped I/O functions?
2. Completion Notification Order in IOCP:
It's mentioned that in IOCP model servers, completion notifications might not arrive in the order the I/O was initiated. However, in my experience with IOCP servers, I've never encountered out-of-order message delivery.

Why doesn't the completion notification order guarantee the sequence of operations?
If the completion notifications are not in order, how is the message order still maintained?

I appreciate any insights or explanations that could help clarify these points!

For question 1, I wonder what the context of that quote is. To me it seems like he's just saying that a driver in general can process requests in whatever order it wants; e.g. the system doesn't forcefully impose any constraints on it. Which should be obvious. In any event, the behavior of WSASend is explicitly documented: "The order of calls made to WSASend is also the order in which the buffers are transmitted to the transport layer."

For question 2, see this answer.

WSASend will be process in order, in which it will be passed to driver. the I/O can complete in any order. and you not need care of order, when process I/O completion. the IOCP here unrelated at all

If the I/O operations are on the same object (in this case, a socket), then they will be processed and completed in the order that they are requested. They have to be, or else bad things can happen to the data/commuication. But, if the operations are on different objects, then the order is not guaranteed, eg a request on objects A and B, B can complete before A.
